# Path position with respect to slider value not set correctly

Tags: slider, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I am trying to add a Path to a Group also containing a `Slider` in my JavaFX app, in order to let the user mark certain characteristics of the object associated with that `Slider` value. However, the Path (a vertical line in this case) isn't being marked at exactly the right position. For smaller values it is before the thumb and for larger values it is after it.

```
double pixelsPerValue = slider.getWidth() / (slider.getMax() - slider.getMin());
double leftAdjust = slider.getLayoutX();
double pathX = leftAdjust + (slider.getValue() * pixelsPerValue);
Path path = PathBuilder.create()
    .elements(
        new MoveTo(pathX, 0)
        , new LineTo(pathX, 25)
        )
    .stroke(Color.CYAN)
    .strokeWidth(3)
    .translateX(0)
    .translateY(27.0)
    .build();
```

Note two things:

1. The Group is in a HBox at the Bottom of a BorderPane;
2. The max value of the Slider is determined by the number of objects
   the user wants to scroll through, could be e.g. 8,617, 10,492, 6,345
   -- you get the idea.

Any idea why is this happening? And how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few notes;

1. The slightly slipping of the line you have drawn, is due to the left
   and right margins between the border and the slider line of the
   slider. You can test it by changing the `double margin` value in
   the code below.
2. You cannot use `slider.getWidth()` until the
       stage is shown. See the "before" and "after" printings in the code
       below. Instead I used `slider.getPrefWidth()`. Ofcourse if you are
       using getWidth() in some event handler then no problem.
3. Use bindings for more easy control and coding. Slide the thumb in the code below.

public class SliderDemo extends Application {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green");
        slider.setLayoutX(60);
        slider.setLayoutY(50);
        slider.setMax(200);
        slider.setValue(180);
        slider.setMin(100);
        slider.setPrefWidth(390);

        double margin = 10; // left and right margins between the border and the slider line of the slider

        SimpleDoubleProperty pixelsPerValueProperty = //
                new SimpleDoubleProperty((slider.getPrefWidth() //
                - (2 * margin)) / (slider.getMax() - slider.getMin()));

        SimpleDoubleProperty pathXProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        pathXProperty.bind(slider.layoutXProperty()//
                .add(margin)//
                .add(pixelsPerValueProperty.multiply(slider.valueProperty().subtract(slider.getMin()))));

        MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(0, 0);
        moveTo.xProperty().bind(pathXProperty);
        LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(0, 25);
        lineTo.xProperty().bind(pathXProperty);

        Path path = PathBuilder.create().elements(
                moveTo, lineTo)//
                .stroke(Color.CYAN)//
                .strokeWidth(3)//
                .translateX(0)//
                .translateY(77.0)//
                .build();

        Group group = new Group(slider, path);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(group, 700, 250));
        System.out.println("before slider.getWidth() = " + slider.getWidth());
        primaryStage.show();
        System.out.println("after slider.getWidth() = " + slider.getWidth());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks - this works. I changed the binding code slightly for my purpose, which was to set a permanent marker at user-determined position on the slider:

Answer (score 0):

```
private void addMarker() {

       double margin = 7; // left and right margins between the border and the slider line of the slider

        SimpleDoubleProperty pixelsPerValueProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty( //
                (slider.getPrefWidth() - (2 * margin)) / (slider.getMax() - slider.getMin())); // need preferred width even though called from keystroke handler

        SimpleDoubleProperty pathXProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        pathXProperty.bind(slider.layoutXProperty()//
                .add(margin)//
                .add(pixelsPerValueProperty.multiply(slider.valueProperty().subtract(slider.getMin())))//
        );

        double currentValue = pathXProperty.doubleValue(); 
        MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(0, 0);
        moveTo.setX(currentValue);
        LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(0, 25);
        lineTo.setX(currentValue);

        Path myTick = PathBuilder.create()
            .elements(
                moveTo
                , lineTo
                )
            .stroke(Color.CYAN)
            .strokeWidth(3)
            .translateX(0)     // for path instantiated in FXML = 7.0
            .translateY(27.0)
            .managed(true)
            .build();

        pathGroup.getChildren().add(myTick);

}
```